# Why I can't use a single version for std::forward that takes a forwarding reference like std::move?

Tags: c++, forwarding-reference

I've read on `std::forward` which is a function template, its purpose is to preserve the details of its argument passing it (forwarding it) to another function. The details include `const`, reference...

It comes in handy when called from inside another function template that have some parameters as universal (forwarding) references to a type parameters.

So I've implemented my version this way:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
T&& forward_(T&& entity)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(entity);
}


template <typename T>
T&& forward_(T& entity)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(entity);
}


template <typename T, typename U, typename F>
void call_fcn(T&& x, U&& y, F func)
{
    func(forward_<T>(x), forward_<U>(y));
}

void swap_(int& x, int& y)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(x, y);
}

void print(int&& a, int&& b)
{
    std::cout << a << '\t' << b << '\n';
}

int main()
{

    int a = 7, b = 5;
    std::cout << a << '\t' << b << '\n';
    call_fcn(a, b, swap_);
    std::cout << a << '\t' << b << '\n';

    call_fcn(1, 2, print);


    std::cout << "\nDone!\n";
}
```

The output:

```
    7   5
    5   7
    1   2
```

- Why the second version is needed for `r-values`?
- As I guess the first version is sufficient because after reference collapsing the right value is returned (l-value ref or r-value ref) which I guess there is no need for the second version.
- Am I missing something in my implementation? I've seen something like `std::eneble_if` in `forward` but I am still learning step by step. Thank you!
- The second version of `forward_` doesn't take a forwarding reference? it takes an l-value reference to the template type parameter?

Comment: what other question did you read? When there are similar Q&As better explain in what way they do not answer your question, otherwise your question might get closed as a duplicate of something that looks like answering your question.

Comment: in any case we cannot clarify what you read unless you tell us what you read and what specifically you didn't understand

Comment: I've not understand why I need a version of `forward` to take just an l-value reference to type parameter and not a forwarding reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-using-stdforward-and-which-problems-it-solves One of the answers explains why two cases have to be considered